# Why is the same input returning two different MD5 hashes?

Tags: php, md5

Alright, I have two files. They are the EXACT SAME.

The first file is:
`http://iadsonline.com/servconfig.php`

And the second file is:
`http://xzerox.info/servconfig.php`

However, when I use md5_file() to get their MD5, They return two different MD5's.

The first returns `cc7819055cde3194bb3b136bad5cf58d`, which is incorrect, and the second returns `96a0cec80eb773687ca28840ecc67ca1`, which is correct.

The file is simply an `&nbsp;`

To verify, I've used this code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($URL);
echo htmlentities($contents);
```

And they both return `&nbsp;`

So why is it hashing them differently?

Comment: The obvious answer is because they are different. See the newline answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one ends in a newline, the first does not.

Answer (score 3):

Trying with `curl`, I see the first one is `&nbsp;` **without** a newline after it, the second one is `&nbsp;` **with** a newline after it.  So of course they'll hash differently.  And indeed, even at the command line (bash prompt):

```
$ md5 sc.dat 
MD5 (sc.dat) = cc7819055cde3194bb3b136bad5cf58d
$ md5 zz.dat
MD5 (zz.dat) = 96a0cec80eb773687ca28840ecc67ca1
```

Comment: You can also run `echo "&nbsp;" | md5sum` versus `echo -n "&nbsp;" | md5sum`

Answer (score 0):

Could you have whitespace in either of those files? Open them up in a text editor and *show all characters*.

Alternatively, run something like this

```
echo str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r"), '[I AM HIDING!]', file_get_contents($URL));
```

If you see *[I AM HIDING!]*, you will know what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

this also happened with me. I set the same encoding (utf-8 without BOM) to all files that store and retrieve hashed strings :) now md5() gives the same results :)